# populate values from another data frame based on predefined set of columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have two data frames. The first one look like that:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Hugo_Symbol=c("CDKN2A", "JUN", "IRS2","MTOR",
                           "NRAS"),
                  A183=c(-0.19,NA,2.01,0.4,1.23),
                  A185=c(0.11,2.45,NA,NA,1.67),
                  A186=c(1.19,NA,2.41,0.78,1.93),
                  A187=c(2.78,NA,NA,0.7,2.23),
                  A188=c(NA,NA,NA,2.4,1.23))
head(df1)
  Hugo_Symbol  A183 A185 A186 A187 A188
1      CDKN2A -0.19 0.11 1.19 2.78   NA
2         JUN    NA 2.45   NA   NA   NA
3        IRS2  2.01   NA 2.41   NA   NA
4        MTOR  0.40   NA 0.78 0.70 2.40
5        NRAS  1.23 1.67 1.93 2.23 1.23
```

The second data frame is smaller and have an empty values:

```
df2 <- data.frame(Hugo_Symbol=c("CDKN2A", "IRS2", "NRAS"),
                  A183=c(0, 0, 0),
                  A187=c(0, 0, 0),
                  A188=c(0, 0, 0))
head(df2)
  Hugo_Symbol A183 A187 A188
1      CDKN2A    0    0    0
2        IRS2    0    0    0
3        NRAS    0    0    0
```

I would like to populate the second data frame with values from the first data frame. The final result will look like that:

```
  Hugo_Symbol  A183 A187 A188
1      CDKN2A -0.19 2.78 NA
2        IRS2  2.01 NA   NA
3        NRAS  1.23 2.23 1.23
```

I tried `cbind()` and `merge()` functions, but they do not work on data with different number of raws and columns.

I would appreciate any help!

Thank you!
Olha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use semi_join from dplyr:
your final table has unexpected values.
my version:

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- df1 %>%  semi_join(df2, by="Hugo_Symbol") %>% 
  select(Hugo_Symbol, A183, A187, A188)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't get the logic of your output, I hope you wrote it wrong, but I think you want the following:

```
matchedRowInds <- match(df2$Hugo_Symbol,df1$Hugo_Symbol)
matchedColInds <- match(colnames(df2),colnames(df1))
newdf <- df1[matchedRowInds,matchedColInds]

# > newdf
#   Hugo_Symbol  A183 A187 A188
# 1      CDKN2A -0.19 2.78   NA
# 3        IRS2  2.01   NA   NA
# 5        NRAS  1.23 2.23 1.23
```

Idea: Get the matching rows in the bigged dataframe which are present in the smaller. Same with columns.

Answer (score 1):

here is a data.table approach... are you sure your desires output in the question is correct? seems to me like IRS2 - A188 should be NA and not 2.23 ?

```
library( data.table )
#make them both data.tables
setDT(df1); setDT(df2)
#find the common columns
comcols <- intersect( names(df1[,-1]), names(df2[,-1]) )
#create a data.table syntax for an update join on the common columns
expr <- paste0( "df2[ df1, `:=` (", 
                 paste0( comcols, " = i.", comcols, collapse = " ," ), 
                 " ), on = .(Hugo_Symbol) ]" )
eval(parse(text=expr))

df2
#    Hugo_Symbol  A183 A187 A188
# 1:      CDKN2A -0.19 2.78   NA
# 2:        IRS2  2.01   NA   NA
# 3:        NRAS  1.23 2.23 1.23
```

Comment: This gives me TRUE statement instead of actual values, when I am running on bigger dataset.